# Add minutes to DateTime till it reaches the period

Tags: php, datetime, for-loop, datetime-format

Hello people here is my code below,

```
        for($minutes_to_add=30;$start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i') == $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i');$minutes_to_add+30)
        {
            $start_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));
            $time_period = $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
            echo $time_period;
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

Iam trying to add `30 minutes` to `$start_date` till it reaches to `end_date`... its not displaying anything...with no error messages...`start_date` and `end_date` both are inside `newDatetime()` any ways to fix this?? in php

Comment: I think you need to use <= instead of ==

Comment: @Naruto yes that was the prob i gues.. i would have accepted ur answer, if it was answered...

Comment: You don't need to `format` the DateTime objects, they can be directly compared. If you *have to* convert them them, use `getTimestamp()`, then at least you work with integers instead of strings.

Comment: Friend Why answer what you can fix in a simple comment? But if you want to upvote an answer, @Ixg is right about the timestamps as integers tough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a 'cleaner' solution, taking in notice that **$start_date** and **$end_date** are Datetime objects:

```
 for($minutes_to_add=30;$start_date->getTimestamp() <= $end_date->getTimestamp();$minutes_to_add+30)
 {
     $start_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));
     $time_period = $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
     echo $time_period;
     echo '<br>';
 }
```